# Updating Scipy module 0.18 version to 1.2.1 version

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry pi 3B+ and python 2.7.

I am using scipy 0.18 version but I want to update 1.2.1 version. How can I do that?

I tried to these comment but it did not work. Please help!!

```
sudo pip install update scipy

pip install scipy

sudo apt-get upgrade python3-scipy
```

Comment: Can you update your question and provide error message?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade scipy` can be useful

Comment: @RoshanBagdiya I tried but there was an error about no upgrading version.

Comment: @ololobus I closed the raspi, but it was about some dispackages